# In RL how to tell an agent that some actions in the action space are currently not available in gym?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, markov-chains

I want to make a task allocation decision by reinforcement learning. Suppose there are N tasks to be allocated and M severs to complete these task.
However, there is a constraint that one task should be served by only one server.How should I design the action space?

So when I design the decision-making action space,I don't know which design is better:

```
        self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([2]*(M*N)) #the first way-action space: [a_11,a_12,...,a_1N,a_M1,a_M2,...,a_MN]  M*N discrete vector,a_mn in [0,1]
        self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([M]*N) #the second way-action space: [a_1,a_2,...,a_N] N discrete vector, a_n in [0,M-1]
```

In first way, the variable a_mn stands for if the n-th task  is offloaded to m-th server or not. While in the second way,a_n represents which server should be chosen by the n-th task.

If the first way is better, how can I implement the constraints mentioned before, since there is lots of infeasible actions in the action space?

Thank a lot

Comment: You are looking for "invalid action masking". Although, I'm a bit skeptical about this approach in general, there is a ready-made implementation of this technique for PPO model in stable-baselines which you may find interesting: https://sb3-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo_mask.html

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I heard this way before but got still a little confused.In your opinion if the first way is better?

Comment: You mean how to design action space in general or how to design invalid actions masking? If you mean the first, then I would probably define a `MultiDiscrete` space of size `M+1 x N`, so that the first M actions represent allocating the task to a specific server (0 to M-1), the last action (M) represents not allocating the task to any server. In terms of gymnasium spaces, it is something like that: `self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([self.num_servers + 1] * self.num_tasks)`. If you ask how to do masking, check sb3 contrib docs, there is an example of such an environment.

Comment: Thx a lot, that's really a good advice for me.By the way, if I design the action space like you said and use the Deep Q Network(DQN) to train, then there will be (M+1)^N kinds of possible action, which means the output layer of the network that contains (M+1)^N nodes, when M and N get bigger, will it become difficult to train?Or do you have any other good suggestions for the training structure?

Comment: you have to flatten your action space to make it `Discrete` to be able to apply DQN. And yes, the more actions you have, the harder it is for DQN to solve the task. From my subjective experience, up to 100 actions at all should be okay with fine-tuning, more than that probably not

Comment: That's clearer for me.Thank u very much for your comment,I'll make a try :)